# WebRequest.Create Exception on DMZ server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm not positive my issue is entirely code or a network issue, though not likely as my site works otherwise.  In a round-about description, I've created a website that is hosted in the DMZ of my employer.  It's an MVC asp.net C# webform that submits test payment transaction data to a test production environment within the company.  A user fills in some fields, and presses the submit button in IE and IE takes over from there and displays the response from the internal test production server. So far, so good.  Now..., I'm changing it so the submission goes through a Controller I have, grabbing the data and sending it to the same internal test production server where I'm now getting an exception on the 'Stream datastream...' line.

```
              HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(selectedServer);     // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            request.Method = "POST";                                                        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.                
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TransactionData);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";                      // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.

            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;                                       // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();                                 // Get the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);                               // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Close();                                                             // Close the Stream object.

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();                       // Get the response.
```

The exception is: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

```
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 'some.ip.address.255:7969' at System.Net"
```

The TransactionData is a string.
Thanks in advance and let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: For what it's worth, this issue still exists. I can open a telnet from the DMZ machine to the target internal production server.

Comment: Solved.  Turns out I needed to add a host entry pointing to the internal server!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Turns out I needed to add a host entry pointing to the internal server!
Maybe someone in the future will find this just as useful?